# Unit testing WCF calls, is it possible and how?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I'm working on a tool that checks some large application functionality. All of my calls to large application are made using WCF, application is too big to create Mock out of it. I want to create Unit Tests for my tool so i won't break functionality while re-factoring or extending functionality.

Is it possible and how ?

Comment: Why do you say your app is to big to create a Mock? Is there any design problem that won't let you use a mock ?

Comment: I guess you should focus on that first, and then create unit tests incrementally. Just the fact that you need to wait for a remote call, and that you will need data in your DB for a test case to be succesful is going to be very painful to create/maintain

Answer (score 1):

You can, but they won't be unit tests in the normal sense of the word, they will be more like automated regression tests. A typical test method might contain the following:

1. Write expected test data into the database
2. Make the WCF call
3. Read data out of the database and assert that it's what you expect
4. Reset the database if necessary

It takes a lot of care to get this right, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "application is too big to create Mock out of it" raised a warning sign. I do not mean to sound harsh but if your application logic cannot be broken down into smaller unit-testable parts then there's something wrong with the architecture of the application.

I've been unit testing WCF powered Silverlight ViewModels for years using Moq with great results. A concept which can be applied to ASP.Net/MVC as well.

Comment: "Big Application" is not mine to re-design.

Comment: but you will be refactoring it, consider making it testeable as refactoring too

Comment: I'm going to re-factor the tool application not the application i test with the tool

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends whether you're looking at unit testing the classes behind the service or functionally testing the service itself.

For functional testing of WCF services I use WCF Storm which could do with a little polish, but works great. You can build and run functional tests as well as performance tests. Very useful little tool.

http://www.wcfstorm.com/